# Mapping, updating and working with claims in general

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, claims

When working with claims in web apps (or any type of app actually) we typically use claim types to find and retrieve claims either from the token or from the datastore.

After working with claims for a while I figure it is a bit cumbersome to deal with types but don't know what the alternatives are.

For instance, if we had to update User object from incoming view model or message, we'd just do

```
user.InjectFrom(vm)
```

or

```
user = mapper.Map<User>(vm)
```

But when working with claims I find it hard having to always use the type/name, e.g.

```
UpdateClaim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, currentClaims, vm.Email)
```

The lack of mapping when dealing with claims is an issue for me.

What is the correct way this is typically done?

Comment: Why are you updating the claims like this?

Comment: @Brad Well the question I asked is how to update them another way so feel free to share the correct way

Comment: Sorry, it's just that claims are generally loaded for the ClaimsPrincipal on each request and not changed afterwards.  If you need to update a claim then you update your User record where the claims are derived.

Comment: I think, You should update User in database, then issue a new JWT token with new claims. Or I didn't understand the question?

Comment: @Brad in ASP.NET Core 2 Identity there are ApplicationUser which is IdentityUser and a separate ClaimsPrincipal. The ApplicationUser does not have Claims and Roles properties anymore and they have to be updated separately/manually, I guess. Updating User only updates user properties in the AspNetUsers table and working with claims is separate through AddClaim, RemoveClaim and ReplaceClaim methods on the UserManager. Still, before one can call that methods, mapping has to be done from the incoming model(s).

Comment: @Artem As I replied to Brad the User no longer has any notion of Claims or Roles and as such when updating user don't get updated.